# Ubuntu Server 16.04 error 60: SSL certificate problem

Tags: server, apache2, 19.04, ssl, curl

Ubuntu server 16.04 PHP7.4 Apache2 running wordpress Geotrust SHA256 certificate

I have started getting the following error

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I have read through and tried most solutions on the many questions on here, but to no avail

The latest 2 i have tried is adding to php.ini the following 2 lines and restarted Apache and rebooted after each one to see if it solves the issue. But it does not

After downloading a fresh copy of cacert.pem The first one i tried was

```
curl.cainfo = "/path/to/cacert.pem"
```

Then i tried

```
openssl.cafile = "/path/to/cacert.pem"
```

But i still get the same error

Any assistance greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: How did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually placed this config in the Apache host file for the 443 connection.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/your_cert_name.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.your_key_name.co.uk.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/your_intermediate.crt
```

Hope that helps